# SQL Server job step - execute sql file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, jobs

what would be the best way to execute sql file ,which has list of insert statements through the job step?

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: create a store proc with list of insert statement and call it on job.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 r2

Comment: The version doesn't matter. When you add a Job step you *do* have the option of specifying a file. *Why* would you use a job for a file of INSERT statements though? Do you really want to repeat this? Or is it a one-off job that can be performed by `sqlcmd` ?

Comment: Have you considered the security implications? Anyone could modify this file and execute statements on the server without getting noticed.

Answer (score 0):

I would store your code in a stored procedure and then execute it in the job step. The simplest reason for this is that if you need to change/add to your code in the future, you don't have to dig into the job itself but instead just update the stored procedure.